# Running fortune from fish shell function

Tags: fish

I'm trying to write a function `quickgit` that automatically adds, commits, and pushes with the added benefit of the commit message coming from `fortune`. I have the following script:

```
function quickgit
    git add --all
    git commit -m (fortune)
    git push
end
```

Which works except the commit message is `"(fortune)"` instead of being a message from fortune. How do I make sure that `fortune` is run and expanded in my fish function?

Comment: Note that I have a bash alias that does this perfectly and the code is `alias quickgit='git add --all; git commit -am "$(fortune)"; git push;'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fish` has enough issues with the finer points of getting quoting just right that I'd avoid using it in scripts entirely. (See https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/159)

I was unable to reproduce your exact issue, but ran into ones of my own around multi-line fortunes. (see the referenced bug)

That being said, for your use case you can avoid it entirely with:

```
function quickgit
    git add --all
    fortune | git commit -F -
    git push
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Command substitution splits the output of the command on newline boundaries by default. So a multi-line fortune will pass multiple arguments to the `git commit -m`. That means only the first line will be handled by the -m option and the second thru n'th lines will end up being treated as file names. Try adding `set -l IFS` to your function to inhibit that splitting. Another approach is to capture the output in a var then interpolate the var:

`set -l fortune (/usr/games/fortune)
git commit -m "$fortune"`

But note that will replace each newline with a space.